# how to export excel from Html table without last row using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can export excel from html table .but could not avoid last row (tr),which row is for pagination on screen.so this row also shows in result of excel file?

```
function DownloadToExcel(table){
  debugger;
  var t = document.getElementById(table);
  t.border = 1;
  var html = t.outerHTML;
  html = encodeURIComponent(html);

  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + html;

  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = uri;
  downloadLink.download = "sauberkeit.xlsx";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the last row before serialising the HTML, then add it back again.

```
var t = document.getElementById(table);
t.border = 1;
var last = t.lastElementChild;
t.removeChild(last);
var html = t.outerHTML;
t.appendChild(last);
...
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.your logic is correct.thanks for this.

I have changed your script little bit only.

var lastRow = table.rows[ table.rows.length - 1 ];
var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
var html=table.outerHTML;
table.appendChild(lastRow);

Comment: @GowthamAlan If this solved your problem, don't forget to click the tick under the voting arrows to mark this answer as "accepted".

Comment: I know ,but i am newbie here ,so i should have reps to put votting.once i got i will vote for u..

Comment: @GowthamAlan You don't need any reputation points to accept an answer.

Comment: @GowthamAlan Thanks! :-)